# Duplicate entry for primary key on MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, primary-key, duplicates

My table just has single column `ID` (passwords for admin Log-in)

Because this code runs every time that program starts, I can prevent errors occurs on `creating database` and `creating tables` by using `IF NOT EXIXTS` statement.

Since `adminLogin` table should be initial first time, When user re-run the program, the `Duplicate entry for primary key` error occurs.

I used `IF NOT EXISTS` for inserting into table, But there is some another error!

My table:

[image: first screen]

Error:

[image: second screen]

Comment: Teach yourself to look at the MySQL documentation when you get a syntax error. (Insert statement doesn't take a WHERE clause.)

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to insert same value. 
PK should be unique.

SET ID as autoincrement.

```
CREATE TABLE `table_code` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `your_column` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility

```
INSERT INTO adminLogin(ID) VALUES(100) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ID=ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use INSERT IGNORE instead.

INSERT IGNORE INTO ADMINLOGIN VALUES(200);

Comment: Note that `IGNORE` should be used with care because it will ignore not only duplicate errors, but other errors as well.

Answer (score 0):

INSERT IGNORE 
INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ... 
REPLACE INTO can all work without erroring. Depending on your needs, some may be a better use than others.

Here's a brief pros and cons of each:

INSERT IGNORE:
Pros: Easy to write
Cons: if data that is being inserted is newer the older data will be preserved

INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ... 
Pros: Can Insert or update specific columns that could have more recent data
Cons: A little harder to write the query for

REPLACE INTO 
Pros: Can insert and update columns that could have more recent data. Faster than Insert, on duplicate key update.
Cons: Overwrites every column even though only some columns may have newer data. IF you are inserting multiple rows replace into could potentially overwrite data for existing rows that you don't really want to overwrite.